# Post method works fine in postman but when i try to use axios in react is giving me some errors

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, postman, backend

Im using node.js, express, multer. to upload data about a product and the files, first the product is being created in the database, then im uploading the files to aws s3 and getting the urls and saving them in a table called imagenes_${productname}. when i use postman everything just works fine,[postman request with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dCni.png).

this is my function that works with postman

```js
const addProduct = async (req, res) => {

    // req.files contains an array of uploaded files

    const files = req.files;
    const urls = [];

    const precio_final = parseInt(req.body.precio)
    const product = req.body.product;
    let q = '';
    let values = [];



    try {
        for (const file of files) {
            const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);
            const folderName = product + "/";
            const key = folderName + file.originalname;
            const params = {
                Bucket: 'pisos-parador-colombia',
                Key: key,
                Body: fileStream
            };

            const command = new PutObjectCommand(params);
            await s3Client.send(command);

            // File uploaded successfully
            const fileUrl = `https://pisos-parador-colombia.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/${key}`;
            urls.push(fileUrl);
        }
        if (product === "pisos_laminados" || product === "pisos_estructurados") {
            q = `INSERT INTO ${product} (titulo,precio,descripcion, trafico, grosor, junta , medidas) VALUES (?)`

            values = [
                req.body.titulo,
                precio_final,
                req.body.descripcion,
                req.body.trafico,
                req.body.grosor,
                req.body.junta,
                req.body.medidas
            ]

        }
        else {
            q = `INSERT INTO ${product} (titulo,precio,descripcion) VALUES (?)`

            values = [
                req.body.titulo,
                precio_final,
                req.body.descripcion,

            ]

        }

        db.query(q, [values], (err, data) => {
            if (err) return res.json(err)

            console.log("product has been created succesfully!");
            const laminateFloorId = data.insertId;

            // Store the URLs in the images_laminatefloors table with the laminate_floor_id
            for (const url of urls) {
                const imageValues = [url, laminateFloorId];
                const imageQuery = `INSERT INTO imagenes_${product} (image_url, product_id) VALUES (?, ?)`;
                db.query(imageQuery, imageValues, (err, imageData) => {
                    if (err) console.error(err);
                    else console.log('Image URL has been stored successfully!');
                });
            }

        })


        res.status(200).send("everything added succesfully");
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("este es el error" + err.message());
        res.status(500).send('Failed to upload files');
    }


}

module.exports = addProduct;
```

But when I use axios and pass the same data, it is giving me this error

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:645:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/danielmonroy/Desktop/pisos_parador_sql/backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/danielmonroy/Desktop/pisos_parador_sql/backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:174:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/danielmonroy/Desktop/pisos_parador_sql/backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:278:15)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/danielmonroy/Desktop/pisos_parador_sql/backend/controllers/addProduct.js:72:33)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/danielmonroy/Desktop/pisos_parador_sql/backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (/Users/danielmonroy/Desktop/pisos_parador_sql/backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)
    at Sequence.end (/Users/danielmonroy/Desktop/pisos_parador_sql/backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/Users/danielmonroy/Desktop/pisos_parador_sql/backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:92:8) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

Im not sure what I have wrong with my code. Everything works when using postman but when I use Axios it is giving me the error above.

Comment: If it works with Postman and not with Axios, why did you only include your server-side code? The problem is most likely in your client-side Axios code

Comment: The _"headers sent"_ error is because the `db.query()` callback runs **after** `res.status(200)...`. If the query errors it will try and add `res.json()` which cannot be done (you can only send a single response). Move the `res.status(200)...` line **inside** the query callback

Comment: You should consider using the Fetch API instead of Axios. Axios was a useful tool in the past but Fetch has been a stable Web Standard for years now and enables you to use other Web Standard features wuch as the Cache API. [See the MDN docs about the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Answer (score 0):

Problems I can see...

1. If your query errors, you are trying to send two responses. This is the source of the *"headers already sent"* error.

   ```js
   if (err) return res.json(err)
   ```

   and

   ```js
   res.status(200).send("everything added succesfully");
   ```

   Returning from the `query()` callback won't stop the rest of the code from running
2. There's no need to nest `[values]`. You're only doing a single insert

With that in mind, I suggest you use the following

```js
try {
  // upload to S3, create `q` and `values`, etc...

  db.query(q, values, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }

    // ...

    res.status(200).send("everything added succesfully");
  });
} catch (err) {
  res.status(500).send("Failed to upload files");
}
```

---

As for why it works with Postman and not with Axios, I can only imagine you're constructing the request body incorrectly for `multipart/form-data` which results in some of the `req.body` values being incorrect and your query failing.

In order to mix files and other data, you need to `append` or `set` each property individually. For example

```js
const fd = new FormData();
// add your files
for (const file of someFileInput.files) {
  fd.append("files", file);
}

// add other data
fd.append("product", "pisos_laminados");
fd.append("titulo", "roble");
fd.append("precio", "100,000");
// etc

axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/addProduct", fd);
```